# Show growth of number of rows of MySQL table over time in Grafana

Tags: mysql, grafana

I have a table such as this:

| ID | Timestamp |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2023-06-21 19:56:12 |
| 2 | 2023-06-22 19:56:12 |
| 3 | 2023-06-23 19:56:12 |

I want to plot the growth of this table in Grafana based on number of rows added per day. For example, the graph would start at 1 on the 1st day, then 5 on the 2nd day (because 4 new rows were added on that day), and so on. The end goal is to have the chart essentially similar to what a stock price chart looks like - growth over time.

I tried researching this online and [this is where I got the closest](https://community.grafana.com/t/row-count-cumulative-frequency-graph/12554) but it still doesn't accomplish what I want.

Comment: What is your exact problem? You don't know how to write sql query for this? Or you don't know how to visualize result of that query?\

Comment: I don’t know how to visualize this in Grafana @markalex